# Visible HDRI with turned on transparency

Tags: rendering, transparency, error, hdri

Why Blender keep saving my image with visible HDRI?

I really don't need it visible. Everything goes fine until its done.

How I can fix it?

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
Found solution. I had to uncheck camera in ray visibility and it works now!

Comment: Is that an HDR image you plugged in your world shader via an *Environment Texture* node?

Comment: I am using pro lighting: skies actually... I tried using it via that node and still same issue

Comment: Please to not edit your post to write answers. Post an actual answer instead. I'd like to see your world shader, you shouldn't need to disable any camera ray visibility for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the Render output, check the <kbd>Transparent</kbd> option in the <kbd>Film</kbd> section of the <kbd>Render Properties</kbd>:

[image]